# Find dictionary with greatest date less than or equal to variable, return value

Tags: python, date, match

I installed the python [package](https://github.com/zachwill/fred/blob/master/fred/core.py)  `fred`, using `pip install fred`, to obtain real time data from the FRED / ALFRED API.

My task now is to match an *assessment* date to the data -- so to extract values associated with the greatest `realtime_date` that's less than or equal to what i'm calling the assessment date (`aDate`).

The data itself is returned in a python dictionary, which contains lists, with each observation stored in a dictionary along with some meta-data -- each observation dict contains: a reference date (`date`), the realtime period that the request covered (`realtime_end`, `realtime_start`) and the value (`value`).

I can see how to match the data to an assessment date when there is an exact match, but in the real world these are the exception.  I am looking for help to generalise this to an inequality.

(note below i am using a variable `fredKey` -- whereas you must supply your own FRED API key to access FRED).

```
import fred
fred.key(fredKey)
CPIobvs = fred.observations('CPIAUCSL', realtime_start = "1990-01-01")
aDate == "2008-02-15"

for i in range(1, len(CPIobvs['observations']['observation'])):
    if CPIobvs['observations']['observation'][i]['realtime_start'] == aDate:
        print (CPIobvs['observations']['observation'][i]['date'], 
                CPIobvs['observations']['observation'][i]['value']
               )
```

For this example, I chose an annual benchmark revision date, to be sure to get something back.  In practice, I am usually going to be updating the simulation on dates where noting happened -- in which case my method returns nothing.

The solution seems to be to match to the greatest date (a `realtime_start` value) that's less than or equal to the assessment date (say `aDate == "2008-02-14"`).  How might i match to the greatest `realtime_date` that's less than or equal to `aDate`?

thanks

Comment: Might I suggest whatever you do have something like ``obs = CPIobvs['observations']['observation']``  outside the for loop; to save possible typos and readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to identify the candidates by filtering out all items in `CPIobvs['observations']['observation']` where `'realtime_start'` `>` `aDate`.

I would do this as a [*generator expression*](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
candidates = (ob for ob in CPIobvs['observations']['observation'] if
    ob['realtime_start'] <= aDate)
```

If you want to see the details, you could form a [*list comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in your interpreter:

```
[ob for ob in CPIobvs['observations']['observation'] if
    ob['realtime_start'] <= aDate]
```

Once these candidates are identified, then use the in-built [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function, providing a lambda for the `key`, which uses the value of `'realtime_start'` to sort the candidate `dict`s:

```
last_ob = max(candidates, key=lambda ob: ob['realtime_start'])
```

The details you require are now in `last_ob['date']` and `last_ob['value']`.

Comment: +1, thanks. I don't fully understand what's going on: i have checked the type of the candidates object, and it's a `generator` - not fully sure what that is.  The reason i ask is that each element of the list `obsList = CPIobvs['observations']['observation']` is a `dict` of the following form: `{'date': '2013-01-01', 'realtime_end': '9999-12-31', 'realtime_start': '2013-02-21', 'value': '231.198'}`. My aim is to print the `obsList['date'], obsList['value']` pairs, subject to the condition that it's the largest `obsList['realtime_start']` date associated with the date.

Comment: i realised that my comment was really another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180767/subset-list-based-on-value-of-dictionary-element), so i accepted and posted another. thanks