# Subset list based on value of dictionary element

Tags: python, list, subset

I have a list which is made up of dictionaries. I wish to subset the list, selecting the dictionaries based a comparison of element values (in this case, selecting only one dictionary per date, with the dict that's selected being the one with the largest `realtime_start` value).

An example list is:

```
obs = [{'date': '2012-10-01',
  'realtime_end': '2013-02-18',
  'realtime_start': '2012-11-15',
  'value': '231.751'},
 {'date': '2012-10-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2012-12-19',
  'value': '231.623'},
 {'date': '2012-11-01',
  'realtime_end': '2013-02-18',
  'realtime_start': '2012-12-14',
  'value': '231.025'},
 {'date': '2012-11-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-01-19',
  'value': '231.071'},
 {'date': '2012-12-01',
  'realtime_end': '2013-02-18',
  'realtime_start': '2013-01-16',
  'value': '230.979'},
 {'date': '2012-12-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-02-19',
  'value': '231.137'},
 {'date': '2012-12-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-03-19',
  'value': '231.197'},
 {'date': '2013-01-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-02-21',
  'value': '231.198'},
 {'date': '2013-01-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-03-21',
  'value': '231.222'}]
```

I wish to subset the list, such that it only contains one dict for each date, with the dict selected which has the largest `realtime_start` value.

In this case, after the list has been subset, it would be:

```
sub = [ {'date': '2012-10-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2012-12-19',
  'value': '231.623'},
 {'date': '2012-11-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-01-19',
  'value': '231.071'},
 {'date': '2012-12-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-03-19',
  'value': '231.197'},
 {'date': '2013-01-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-03-21',
  'value': '231.222'}]
```

Additionally, say i specified a maximum date:

```
maxDate = "2013-02-21"
```

How would i subset such that the `realtime_start` value was *not* greater than maxDate? In this case, i'd expect the following subset:

```
sub2 = [ {'date': '2012-10-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2012-12-19',
  'value': '231.623'},
 {'date': '2012-11-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-01-19',
  'value': '231.071'},
 {'date': '2012-12-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-02-19',
  'value': '231.137'},
 {'date': '2013-01-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-02-21',
  'value': '231.198'} ]
```

How would i write such a subset operation in Python 2.7.3? Is this possible in Python?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to group your entries by the `date` field, and then perform operations on the groups of entries associated with each of those `date`s.  The way I do this sort of thing is to use a plain ol' `dict`.  In such cases, I think of a `dict` as a special kind of `set`—a "decorated set", if you will—, whose every (necessarily hashable) element is "decorated" with some (in general non-hashable) payload (i.e., the associated dictionary value).  In your example, each element of this "decorated set" is one of the possible values for the `date` field among all the dicts in `obs`, and its associated payload is the list of all the dicts in `obs` that have that key as their `date` field.

Thus,

```
In [4]: dobs = dict()
In [5]: for o in obs:
   ...:     d = o['date']
   ...:     if d not in dobs:
   ...:         dobs[d] = []
   ...:     dobs[d].append(o)
   ...:
```

One can use [`dict.setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to write the body of the `for`-loop more succinctly, like this:

```
In [7]: for o in obs:
   ...:     dobs.setdefault(o['date'], []).append(o)
   ...:
```

Or one can pre-load the dictionary with empty lists, and then just append to them without the need to check if the key is already in the dict:

```
In [9]: dobs = dict([(d, []) for d in set([e['date'] for e in obs])])
In [10]: for o in obs:
   ....:     dobs[o['date']].append(o)
   ....:
```

After any of the above, you'll end up with a dictionary, `dobs`, whose keys are `date`'s and whose values are *lists* of all the dicts in `obs` that have the corresponding key as the `date` value.

Now you can go to town with this dict, and apply any kind of function to its values.  For example, to extract, for each `date`, the dict having the most recent `realtime_start`, you could do this:

```
In [11]: rts = lambda x: x['realtime_start']
In [12]: [sorted(e, key=rts)[-1] for e in dobs.values() if e]
Out[12]: 
[{'date': '2013-01-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-03-21',
  'value': '231.222'},
 {'date': '2012-12-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-03-19',
  'value': '231.197'},
 {'date': '2012-10-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2012-12-19',
  'value': '231.623'},
 {'date': '2012-11-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-01-19',
  'value': '231.071'}]
```

(The `if e` qualifier at the end of the comprehension above is not necessary here, but I include it in the name of "defensive programming".  Without it, the code above would fail if any of the values in `dobs` happens to be empty.  We know that this won't be the case for `dobs`, but it may become an issue in a more general setting.  More about this below.)

You also ask how to perform the selection described above while capping `realtime_start` at `2013-02-21`.  For this problem, I find it conceptually cleaner to split the problem into two subproblems: first, generate subset of `dobs` that meet the specified constraint on `realtime_start`; then, perform the same operation as before on the restricted dict.  Thus:

```
In [13]: dobs2 = dict([(k, [d for d in v if d['realtime_start'] <= maxDate])
   ....:               for k, v in dobs.items()])
In [14]: [sorted(e, key=rts)[-1] for e in dobs2.values() if e]
Out[14]: 
[{'date': '2013-01-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-02-21',
  'value': '231.198'},
 {'date': '2012-12-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-02-19',
  'value': '231.137'},
 {'date': '2012-10-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2012-12-19',
  'value': '231.623'},
 {'date': '2012-11-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-01-19',
  'value': '231.071'}]
```

Once again, the `if e` qualifier is not necessary in this case, but if `maxDate` were low enough that some groups ended up empty, then it would be essential.  (Without it, the attempt to access the last element of the first-encountered empty list would raise an `IndexError` exception.)

As you may have noticed, the ordering of the results above differs from yours.  This is because the built-in Python `dict`s do not preserve ordering.  If the ordering of the original `obs` list is significant, then you can replace all calls to `dict` with calls to `collections.OrderedDict`.  E.g.:

```
In [15]: from collections import OrderedDict
In [16]: dobs = OrderedDict()
In [17]: for o in obs:
   ....:     dobs.setdefault(o['date'], []).append(o)
   ....: 
In [18]: [sorted(e, key=rts)[-1] for e in dobs.values()]
Out[18]: 
[{'date': '2012-10-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2012-12-19',
  'value': '231.623'},
 {'date': '2012-11-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-01-19',
  'value': '231.071'},
 {'date': '2012-12-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-03-19',
  'value': '231.197'},
 {'date': '2013-01-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-03-21',
  'value': '231.222'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> # sort so that the same dates are contiguous
>>> obs.sort(key=lambda x: x['date'])
>>> grouped = itertools.groupby(obs, lambda x: x['date'])
>>> m = [max(g, key=lambda x: x['realtime_start']) for k, g in grouped]
>>> 
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(m)
[{'date': '2012-10-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2012-12-19',
  'value': '231.623'},
 {'date': '2012-11-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-01-19',
  'value': '231.071'},
 {'date': '2012-12-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-03-19',
  'value': '231.197'},
 {'date': '2013-01-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-03-21',
  'value': '231.222'}]
```

You can add other conditions too:

```
>>> grouped = itertools.groupby(obs, lambda x: x['date'])
>>> m = [max((w for w in g if w['realtime_start'] <= maxDate),
         key=lambda x: x['realtime_start']) for k, g in grouped]
>>> pprint.pprint(m)
[{'date': '2012-10-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2012-12-19',
  'value': '231.623'},
 {'date': '2012-11-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-01-19',
  'value': '231.071'},
 {'date': '2012-12-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-02-19',
  'value': '231.137'},
 {'date': '2013-01-01',
  'realtime_end': '9999-12-31',
  'realtime_start': '2013-02-21',
  'value': '231.198'}]
```

But I'd recommend looking at my favourite Python data manipulation library, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/): it's great for tabular and time-series data, and data manipulation using it would be much easier (and more R-like in functionality) than anything you could roll yourself.

Comment: out of curiosity; is sorting necessary or just for performance?

Comment: @jurgenreza: it's necessary.  If you have `[1,2,1]`, `groupby` will see that as three groups because the two `1`s aren't contiguous.

Comment: +1, thanks. Sorting is necessary. The data is from ALFRED, and i wish to test various strategies using only the data that was available at each date. I forgot a condition in the post you have replied to -- will `itertools` work with a condition such as `realtime_start` is not greater than `maxDate`?

Comment: @ricardo: sure, you'd just use something like `max(w for w in g if w['realtime_start'] <= maxDate, key=etc)`.  Using strings for date comparisons can lead to problems if the format changes, though, so I'd probably make them `datetime` instances.  As long as you always have things zero-padded it should work as expected, though.

Comment: @DSM could you please show me how to do it. I am totally new to Python (i'm coming from `R`), and such statements make my head spin :)

Comment: I just varied `maxDate` and got an error.  Could you please help? `maxDate = "2013-02-18"` for example yields `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`. I have tried bumping `maxDate` by a month either way (`maxDate = "2013-01-21"` for example) and it fails with `ValueError`. As i am not entirely sure how itertools works, i'm a bit stuck. thanks